# What code in ASP.NET Identity sets the user's security stamp?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

A security stamp is a random value generated based on the user's user name and password.

Following a chain of method calls, I traced the security stamp's origin to the `SecurityStamp` property of the [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class.

However, I am unable to find the code that sets this value. I found only one setter of this property and that is the EntityFramework layer that provides the core storage (`IUserStore<..>`, `IRoleStore<...>`, etc.).

```
// From Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<...>
public virtual Task SetSecurityStampAsync(TUser user, string stamp)
{
    this.ThrowIfDisposed();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    }
    user.SecurityStamp = stamp;
    return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
}
```

However, I found no code that calls into the `SetSecurityStampAsync` method.

This would obviously be reset whenever the user's credentials are changed or when a new user is created.

What code sets this value?

Answer (score 4):

The `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` default `UserManager` uses this method a lot.

It calls it using the internal method `UpdateSecurityStampInternal` and the public method `UpdateSecurityStampAsync`.

The following methods call the internal method:

- CreateAsync
- RemovePasswordAsync
- UpdatePassword
- RemoveLoginAsync
- SetEmailAsync
- SetPhoneNumberAsync
- ChangePhoneNumberAsync
- SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync

You should be able to get the source code for user manager using symbolsource.

Comment: If it helps, .NET Core source code is here:

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs#L792